# Angular Filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a form that is divided into sections like so:

```
education: {faculty: "", high_school: ""}
experience: {experience_1: "", experience_2: "", experience_3: ""}
personalInfo: {id: "", type: "", email: "", password: "", password_new: "", first_name: "", last_name: "",…}
skills: {skill_1: "", skill_2: ""}
```

all inputs are displayed with ngRepeat.

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in user" >
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in val | filter:filterBySection" class="formParameter" >

        <span class="param_label">
            {{k}}:
        </span>

     <span e-class="form-control " class="formParameterValue" editable-text="user.{{key}}.{{k}}" e-name="{{k}}">{{v}}</span>
    </div>   
</div>
```

how would I implement a filter that will display only the chosen section. For example: If I press the education button then show only 'faculty' and 'high school'

```
<li ng-repeat="(a,b) in user" ng-click="filterBySection = ?:{{a}}" ng-model="filterBySection"><a href="#">{{doc_param}}</a></li>
```

Please provide suggestion for it.

Comment: What i did, last time i had to use this, i took 2 lists in my controller. One with all rows, and the other one with the rows that'll be displayed. So, everytime you hit one of your filter button, you regenerate the 2nd list from the full one, while applying your filter ;)

Comment: @dor Is there anything else I can do, or any other information you can provide that can help us answer this question for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can show different div containers by setting a certain variable by using your button, in this case "tab". Then only the dif with the according tab-value will be shown by testing the value of "tab" with ng-show.

```
// Links or buttons
<a href ng-click="tab = 1"> Description</a>
<a href ng-click="tab = 2"> Specifications</a>

// DIVS
<div class ="panel" ng-show="tab === 1">
   <h4>Description</h4>
   <p>{{product.description}}</p>
</div>
<div class ="panel" ng-show="tab === 2">
   <h4>Specifications</h4>
   <p>{{product.specification}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the built-in filter module, I would create a custom filter that returns a boolean indicating whether the item should be shown or not (using `ng-show`).

Continue having your `<li>`'s set the filterBySection model.

Change the `div` with the `ng-repeat` to something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in val" ng-show="k | filterSelection:filterBySection" class="formParameter" >
```

Then on your `angular.module` object, add a filter like:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.filter('filterSelection', function ($filter) {
    return function (input, section) {
        // insert logic like
        if (section == 'Education' && (input == 'high_school' || input == 'faculty'))
        { return true; }
        // and so on...
    };
});
```